# How do I debug errors for a mobile app that is running on an actual Ipad?

Tags: debugging, ipad, mobile, beta

I have a mobile app that is currently in beta. I have a small group of users that are actively using it. All of them are using it on the same model Ipad. They are all experiencing issues that I cannot replicate on my end (on my PC or on the Ipad I have). Is there anyway to see the code as it is actively running on an actual Ipad (much like chrome developer tools). Maybe some piece of software where if the ipad is hooked up to a mac and I can see the code output as the errors occur. Thanks.

I have not tried anything for this as I don't know where to start

Comment: did you even search for this online? this for example looks promising: https://www.browserstack.com/guide/how-to-debug-on-ipad for future reference I just used the search term "mac debug an ipad app"